# Invoking LostFocus event from RadDatePicker inside a RadGridView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a `RadGridView` inside which I have a `RadDatePicker` I want to fire a `command` on any change with that date.

I am trying to achieve that through

```
<telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Date of Travel" >
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FlightDetails.FltDate, StringFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy}">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <telerikControls:RadDatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=FlightDetails.FltDate,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy}" DisplayFormat="Short" Culture="en-AU">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.DateOfFlightCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type baseview:QRUserControl}}}" 
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </telerikControls:RadDatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewColumn>
```

Nothing is triggered.

Comment: Where is your DateOfFlightCommand property defined? And where is the RadGridView located in the visual tree?

Comment: The DateOfFlightCommand  is in main viewmodel & the RadGridView is in a usercontrol called from main view

Comment: And the MainVM is the DataContext of the window?

Comment: yes it is the datacontext for main window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding is probably invalid. If the `DateOfFlightCommand` property is defined in the view model of the parent window, you should specify `Window` as the the `AncestorType`:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.DateOfFlightCommand, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: Yes indeed I was trying to handle event in main view model but has to do in the child VM.